# Create a group bar chart with an aggregated data frame in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization

I have an aggregated data in three column: fuel type, no of car in 2018 and no of car in 2021, shown as below table. However I am stuck in creating a grouped bar chart to compare the fuel type in 2018 and 2021

[image: aggregated data frame]

I would like to create a grouped bar chart to visualize the change (between 2018 and 2021) to compare them side by side (x-axis = fuel type, y-axis = value of 2018 and 2021).

From my search from Google, most of the teaching requries to convert into matrix or table. However, it just turn out into something "unsual". Thus I am hopping for your help or advice in solving this.

```
table <- table(fuel_trend$2018, fuel_trend$2021)
barplot(table, beside = TRUE)
```

Additionally, I do welcome new suggestion to better visaulize this data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

Basically we bring data in long format and plot with `ggplot2` package:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-fuel_typ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fuel_typ, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma())+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

data:

```
structure(list(fuel_typ = c("DIESEL", "DIESEL/ELECTRIC", "LPG", 
"PETROL", "PETROL/ELECTRIC"), no_car_18 = c(47817L, 14L, 904L, 
333872L, 3653L), no_car_21 = c(3992L, 199L, 2224L, 215199L, 30550L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: @ TarJae: great answer! Will bookmark this for later!

Comment: Hi @TarJae. Many thanks for your help. May I know what is the minus "-" for in the first line of code (pivot_longer(-fuel_typ))?

Comment: bring all in long format but the column `fuel_typ`. Is the same as `pivot_longer(c(no_car_18, no_car_21)`.